# Samba Broken after 13.04->14.04 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, server, samba

I finally updated our in-house file server from 13.04 to 14.04 yesterday.  The upgrade went fine, but sadly, it is no longer much of a file server.  Samba will no longer allow Windows machines to browse the list of shares and only users with an account on the server itself can connect (and THAT requires them to enter their username/password).

Under 13.04 all of our shares were public and did not require users to enter any credentials.  Browsing the list of shares worked great.

I've been trying to poke at the smb.conf file to get it to work with no success.  I found out that 'service samba stop|start|restart' doesn't work, but using smbd (and nmbd, if necessary) DOES work.  I've followed several different sets of configuration instructions, including the ones on the samba wiki, and still nothing is working.  I *MUST* get this working again *FAST*.

I've ensured that ALL shared directories have permission set to 777.  Everything is owned by nobody.  The smbuser was a suggestion from one of the pages that supposedly had the steps to "make it work."

Here's the output from testparm -s:

```
root@fs1:~# testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[agent]"
Processing section "[backups]"
Processing section "[cr3nt4]"
Processing section "[evisd]"
Processing section "[installs]"
Processing section "[save_ak]"
Processing section "[save_dh]"
Processing section "[save_dje]"
Processing section "[save_spv]"
Processing section "[wgpo]"
Processing section "[pics3dev]"
Processing section "[pics3qvcs]"
Processing section "[cr3w2k]"
Processing section "[save_hwm]"
Processing section "[iso]"
Processing section "[mp3]"
Processing section "[save_hdy]"
Processing section "[modcomp]"
Processing section "[evidev]"
Processing section "[fpcdev]"
Processing section "[cr3qvcs]"
Processing section "[cr3ref]"
Processing section "[cr3nt4spv]"
Processing section "[Mcr3nt4]"
Processing section "[Mcr3w2k]"
Processing section "[fplref]"
Processing section "[fplqvcs]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
[global]
        workgroup = EVI
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        interfaces = lo, eth0
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        read only = No
        directory mask = 0777
        guest only = Yes
        guest ok = Yes

[agent]
        comment = Steve's Transient Files
        path = /home/shares/agent
        valid users = smbuser

[backups]
        comment = Other Systems' Backups
        path = /home/shares/backups/
        valid users = smbuser

[cr3nt4]
        comment = CR3 NT4 PICS
        path = /home/shares/cr3_nt4
        valid users = smbuser

[evisd]
        comment = EVI Software Development
        path = /home/shares/fs1/evisd
        valid users = smbuser

[installs]
        comment = Installation Packages
        path = /home/shares/fs1/installs
        valid users = smbuser

[save_ak]
        comment = Al Keet's Backup Area
        path = /home/shares/fs1/SAVE_AK
        valid users = smbuser

[save_dh]
        comment = Don Horsley's Backup Area
        path = /home/shares/DON
        valid users = smbuser

[save_dje]
        comment = Dave Etzold's Backup Area
        path = /home/shares/fs1/save_dje
        valid users = smbuser

[save_spv]
        comment = Steve Valliere's Backup Area
        path = /home/shares/fs1/save_spv
        valid users = smbuser

[wgpo]
        comment = Work Group Post Office
        path = /home/shares/fs1/wgpo
        valid users = smbuser

[pics3dev]
        comment = PICS III Reference Copy
        path = /home/shares/PICS_III_Dev
        valid users = smbuser

[pics3qvcs]
        comment = PICS III QVCS Repository
        path = /home/shares/PICS_III_QVCS
        valid users = smbuser

[cr3w2k]
        comment = CR3 W2K PICS
        path = /home/shares/cr3_w2k
        valid users = smbuser

[save_hwm]
        comment = Howard's Old Files
        path = /home/shares/fs1/save_hwm
        valid users = smbuser

[iso]
        comment = ISO Images
        path = /home/shares/iso
        valid users = smbuser

[mp3]
        comment = MP3 Library
        path = /home/shares/mp3
        valid users = smbuser

[save_hdy]
        comment = Butch's saved stuff.  Hands off!
        path = /home/shares/save_hdy
        valid users = smbuser

[modcomp]
        comment = MODCOMP Sources
        path = /home/shares/MODCOMP
        valid users = smbuser
        case sensitive = Yes
        map archive = No

[evidev]
        comment = CR3 2002 - EVI Sources
        path = /home/shares/fs1/fpc/evidev
        valid users = smbuser

[fpcdev]
        comment = CR3 2002 - FPC Sources
        path = /home/shares/fs1/fpc/fpcdev
        valid users = smbuser

[cr3qvcs]
        comment = CR3 PICS QVCS Repository
        path = /home/shares/cr3qvcs
        valid users = smbuser

[cr3ref]
        comment = CR3 PICS Source Reference Copy
        path = /home/shares/cr3ref
        valid users = smbuser

[cr3nt4spv]
        comment = Steve's CR3 NT4 PICS M Drive
        path = /home/shares/cr3nt4spv
        valid users = smbuser

[Mcr3nt4]
        comment = CR3 NT4 PICS M Drive
        path = /home/shares/Mcr3nt4
        valid users = smbuser

[Mcr3w2k]
        comment = CR3 Win2K PICS M Drive
        path = /home/shares/Mcr3w2k
        valid users = smbuser

[fplref]
        comment = FPL QVCS Reference
        path = /home/shares/FPL_Reference
        valid users = smbuser

[fplqvcs]
        comment = FPL QVCS Database
        path = /home/shares/FPL_QVCS
        valid users = smbuser
```

Help!  Please?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by making these changes to smb.conf:

- add:

  ```
  username map = /etc/samba/username.map
  ```
- username.map contains one line:

  ```
  nobody = *
  ```
- change:

  ```
  map to guest = bad user
  ```

  to

  ```
  map to guest = bad password
  ```
- change:

  ```
  valid user = smbuser
  ```

  to

  ```
  valid user = nobody
  ```

  (in all 27 shares)
- ran:

  ```
  smbuser -a nobody
  ```

  and pressed ENTER for the password

After restarting the smbd service, I was able to browse the server's shares and connect to them without entering any credentials.  This resolves my issue because we have no private user shares on the common server -- everyone is always a guest.

Maybe someone will find my problem/solution helpful.